Github git add . && git commit -a -m “3333” && git branch -M master && git push -u origin main
I have maid the change
[master 8dbe8df] “3333”
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
Everything up-to-date

This shows up on the terminal on mac. But nothing has been updated to my github. When I use VSCode to update the git, then i can see the updated file on my github.
How can I use the command to push the git to my repository?
origin  git@github.com:chichina/test.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com: chichina/test.git (push)


Please edit the question to include the output of git remote -vv

git branch -M master && git push -u origin main — renamed to master but pushing main?

Is this just main vs master? If yes the question should be closed as not reproducible due to a typo. (Or deleting the question works too.)

you are using master not main.
run :
git push origin master

